# springboot using mysql getting NullPointerException error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, tomcat

when i'm calling products post method from postman, i'm getting below error. I'm not sure about what i'm doing wrong.

```
2020-02-25 13:09:39.903 ERROR 2982 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

controller class:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class MyRetailController {

    private ProductService productService = new ProductService();
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyRetailController.class);
    //private Product product = new Product();
    //private static Map<Integer, Product> productRepo = new HashMap<>();

    //This method returns a product using an id from the database.
    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getProductById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws Exception{
        logger.info("MyRetailController.java --> getProduct/{id}() :: START ");
        //System.out.println(productRepo.get(id));
        Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
        logger.info("MyRetailController.java --> getProduct/{id}() :: END ");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(product, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getProducts() {
        logger.info("MyRetailController.java --> getProducts/ :: START ");
        //Product<List<>> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.getAllProducts(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /** This method is used to save products to hashmap **/
    @PostMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) throws Exception{
        logger.info("MyRetailController.java --> products/ :: START ");
        productService.insertProductToDatabase(product);
        logger.info("MyRetailController.java --> products/ :: END ");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Product is created successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

service class

```
@Component
public class ProductService {

    // Will use this class to handle services

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Product product;

    public void insertProductToDatabase(Product product){
        System.out.println("Current price from json " + product.getCurrentPrice());
        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    public void deleteProductFromDatabase(int id){
        productRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return (List<Product>) productRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Product getProductById(int id) throws Exception{
        Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(id);
        return product.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Couldn't find a product wit hid: " + id));
    }



}
```

repository class

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

and pojo

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int productId;
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;
    @Column(name="CURRENT_PRICE")
    private float currentPrice;
    @Column(name="CURRENCY_CODE")
    private String currencyCode;

    public Product(){
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public float getCurrentPrice() {
        return currentPrice;
    }

    public void setCurrentPrice(float currentPrice) {
        this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
    }

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }

    public void setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    }


}
```

Full stack trace

"trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat com.myretail.myRetail.service.ProductService.insertProductToDatabase(ProductService.java:26)\n\tat com.myretail.myRetail.controller.MyRetailController.createProduct(MyRetailController.java:52)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n",
    "path": "/products"

Comment: can you post more of the stacktrace ?

Comment: I added the full stack trace i'm getting. Thank you in advance!

Comment: problem in `private ProductService productService = new ProductService();` declaretion, in this case `@Autowired private ProductRepository productRepository;` is null, because you manually created the servise, please fix to `@Autowired private ProductService productService;` and Spring will properly inject the bean

Comment: @tsarenkotxt answer + adding `@Entity` to your `Product` class should fix the problem.